# Get value between character using preg_match_all PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

This is my code:

```
$str = 'auto_load[>=]';
$result = get_value($str);

function get_value($s) {
   if (preg_match_all('/[(=|>=|<=|~|!~|~!)]/', $str, $m)) {
       //return here...
   }
}
```

I want it return: ">="

```
(accept the return value: "=", ">=", "<=", "~", "!~" or "~!")
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Did you check the content of `$m`?

Comment: It return array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) ">"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "="
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a special character used to open a character class. if you want to write a literal `[` you must escape it *(no need to escape `]`, it isn't a special character even if it can be used to close a character class, the regex engine is smart enough to know when it is the case)*:

```
/\[([><]?=|~!?|!~)]/
```

Comment: awesome, tks so much! <3